# How do I implement a cutting plane functionality using HelixToolkit.Wpf.Sharpdx?

Tags: wpf, sharpdx, plane, helix-3d-toolkit

I can't find a working example of a cutting plane implementation for HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.

I hope to achieve something simpler than the HelixToolkit.Wpf cutting plane which can be invoqued by shift+clic anywhere on the displayed model.

I'll be happy if at least I would be able to do cutting planes with axis-oriented normals, I don't have any interest in custom oriented cutting planes.

### Edit

After answering to first comment, I add the precision about trying to do something after the CrossPlaneSection example from the github, but couldn't find someting to use on a more complicated scene. Still waiting for tips.

Comment: (In general adding voting commentary is a waste of time, since the voter will have long gone, and this meta-material is not of interest to most readers anyway. If you really want to add it to a page, put it in the comments).

Comment: @halfer I'll keep this in mind, thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the cross section example in Sharpdx version

https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/develop/Source/Examples/WPF.SharpDX/CrossSectionDemo

Comment: This example does not show how to cut a complex scene with more than one Model3D. I played a little with the golden vehicle but couldn't find how to insert more objects in the scene and have them cut too.

I tried to use the same object on all my Model3D instances, but it makes the scene impossible to render, FPS fall to 1 or 2.